# Return from function python3

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, variables

just started coding in python3. i have an idea of what i want to do with this program but not sure how i should go about it completely

Ok lets try this again. So say i have three categories of foo, foo1,2 and 3 and in each category of foo there are 6 variables that have unique integers assigned to them

I then ask the user input("Which foo do you like?") which will accept string input so they can say which foo they want. Then i few other questions to ask like

```
input("How many foo do you want") and 
input("How long do you want to loan foo for")
```

As far as the structure of the program goes am i best off creating global variables for the 6 variables per foo category or have 6 local variables per function?

My problem is when i go to calculate

```
number_of_foo_user_chose = input("How many foo do you want")
             if user enters a value less than allowed foo ask again
calcualtefoo(number_of_foo_user_chose, <insert variable to multiply>)
```

The calculatefoo is what im getting stuck at, how can i predict what the user will chose so i can multiply against it?  it seems i cant so i have got a bad layout but im not sure how else i should structure it. hence my question for help.

Thanks :)

Comment: Briefly: "gets back to the original question in main" is called `return`.

Comment: Edited my question, my question was asked incorrectly. ill try again :)

Comment: Have you read the beginnings of [Python 3 tutorial yet?](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/)

Comment: No not yet. Just wanted a tiny bit of guidance as to what functionality i am looking for? Arguments? Parameters?